# Citroen C3 - Passenger Doors Fail to Open

Tags: troubleshooting, citroen, central-locking

I have a Citroen C3 and all passenger doors will not open.

I have reset the immobolizer, pressed the lock buttons inside the car including child locks button, replaced the driver door central locking motor, but still no response. The lights flash when the fob buttons are pressed to open and lock as they should and I can hear the noise as if the central locking is working but they still will not open from inside or outside. I can only open the drivers door with the key

***Can anyone explain howto fix this issue?***

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the lock/unlock solenoid is connected properly? You can unlock ***only*** by using the key on the outside, but not the manual selector on the inside (assuming there is one)?

Comment: Without wiring diagrams it's hard to say. What year is the car? It may be a broken splice if none of the locks work.